# Slick error while compiling table definitions: could not find implicit value for parameter tm

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I am completely new to Slick. I am trying to create a basic table type, but it just doesn't compile. Here's my code:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver._
import scala.slick.lifted.Tag
import scala.slick.lifted.Column
import scala.slick.lifted.ProvenShape

class Documents(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, String, String)](tag, "DOCUMENTS") {
       def id: Column[Long] = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
       def `type`: Column[String] = column[String]("TYPE")
       def data: Column[String] = column[String]("DATA")

       def * : ProvenShape[(Long, String, String)] = (id, `type`, data)
}
```

And I get these errors:

```
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[Long]
              def id: Column[Long] = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)
                                           ^
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[String]
              def `type`: Column[String] = column[String]("TYPE")
                                                   ^
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[String]
              def data: Column[String] = column[String]("DATA")
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Slick 2**

OK, I've solved it while writing the question.
Use

`import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._`

instead of

`import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver._`

---

**UPDATE:** thanks to @lost_trekkie

for **Slick 3** use:

`import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._`

---

**UPDATE:** thanks to Dmytro Mitin

In **Slick 3.2** `slick.driver.PostgresDriver` is deprecated, `slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile` should be used instead:

`import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._`

Comment: In 3.2 `slick.driver.PostgresDriver` is deprecated, `slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile` should be used instead: `import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._`

Answer (score 4):

FYI, with Slick 3, the above mentioned import should be

```
 import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
```